# how to if php, im trying to get condition true then statement

Tags: php, html

```
if(isset($_SESSION["name"])) {
    header("Location:homepage.php");
}
```

how to if `name == udin then {}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the first `if`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['name'] == 'udin') {
        // do something
    } else {
        header("Location: homepage.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you're trying to do if ifelse statement.
you can try:

```php
    if(isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] != 'udin'){
    header("Location:homepage.php"); 
    }elseif(isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] == 'udin'){
    // what to do if $_SESSION["name"] is set, and if name is udin
    }
```

Comment: This won't work, because the first condition will be met even when name is `udin`. It will never enter `elseif`.

Comment: OK. Then I can will edit it, and change that `if(isset($_SESSION["name"] && $_SESSION["name"] != 'udin' ))`. thank you for you comment <3